# Spring Data JPA: How to access a table in another schema with a read only username/schema

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

So I have a database schema/user in an Oracle enterprise database named C##SCOTT called Employee. This schema/user has all the permissions to create tables, update, read and write. I also have another schema/user called C##ORC_READ_ONLY which is set up to have read-only permissions of the tables within the C##SCOTT schema. My application.yml file looks like this if I want to access the database via C##ORC_READ_ONLY:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
    username: C##ORC_READ_ONLY
    password: --password goes here--
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

  jpa:
    database: oracle
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

From my understanding I just code my Entity like this:

```
@Data
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name ="EMPLOYEE", schema="C##SCOTT")
public class Employee {

    @Id                   
    @Column(name = "EMPNO")
    private Long id;

    private String ename;

    private String job;

    private Long mgr;

    private Date hiredate;

    private Long sal;

    private Long comm;

    private Long deptno;

}
```

...and the repo like this:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

The service portion of my demo web-service looks like this:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper employeeObjectMapper;

    public String getAllEmployeesService( ) throws JsonProcessingException {

        List<Employee> employeeArrayList = employeeRepository.findAll();
        GetAllEmployeesResponseWrapper getAllEmployeeResponseWrapper = new GetAllEmployeesResponseWrapper(employeeArrayList);
        String response = employeeObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(getAllEmployeeResponseWrapper);

        return response;

    }
}
```

Everything compiles fine, no warnings or errors regarding access occur. However, if I try to send the request message to the the web-service, I get an exception thrown saying that the table or view cannot be found:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Now if I change the username and password to the schema/username that is the actual owner of the table... it works fine. Do I have to override the `findAll()` method from the repository to get this to work? Or is there something else wrong?

Comment: Try to use C##SCOTT schema in the entity annotation @Table.

Comment: @Mar-Z ... that was a big derp on my part yes C##SCOTT would be correct. It seems like the Oracle database I created doesn't want common users to actually have admin rights to the tables, from what I understand, you can do it, buuuut a  using a non C## name (not a common user) would helped. But later I had problems with Spring Data JPA choking on the hash/ pound sign for some reason. Might be by design. dunno. So solution was to create a database user with admin right and not have to use the C## prefix in the name for the schema / user that owned the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Sooo. My only solution was to create another user that had admin rights... and NOT use the C## prefix. Thus I changed the Model to:

```
@Data
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE", schema= "FRED")
public class Employee {

    @Id                    
    @Column(name = "EMPNO")
    private Long id;

    private String ename;

    private String job;

    private Long mgr;

    private Date hiredate;

    private Long sal;

    private Long comm;

    private Long deptno;

}
```

FRED is not a common user. I think it was how I configured the Oracle database that caused the issue. @Mar-Z and @sergey-tsypanov answers DID help me put it together.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for feedback. According to Oracle doc - common users are only relevant if you have multitenant architecture and need some special users who have the same name in all CDBs or PDBs. They will be recognized by the prefix "C##".

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish between user and schema. Assuming you say

> I have a database schema/user in an Oracle enterprise database named C##SCOTT called Employee.

and

> I also have another schema/user called C##ORC_READ_ONLY which is set up to have read-only permissions of the tables within the C##SCOTT schema.

your entity should look like

```java
@Data
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name ="EMPLOYEE", schema="C##SCOTT")
public class Employee {
}
```

The rest of the code should remain as is (tiny thing: you don't need `@Repository` over an interface extending `JpaRepository` as Spring resolves it automatically).